# How do I edit this snippet in order to show buttons on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I found [this nice snippet](https://codepen.io/sebj54/pen/oxluI) and I wanted to create the same kind of thing but with inline buttons. Adding a `display: inline` seems to not work and it also breaks the visual effect.

This is the HTML file:

```
<h1>Material design buttons (CSS-only)</h1>

<h2>Material design buttons with a ripple effect. This is CSS-only so there is no mouse detection, the ripple effect always starts from the same point.</h2>

<button class="btn" type="button"><span>Button</span></button>

<button class="btn orange" type="button"><span>Medium-length button</span></button>

<button class="btn red" type="button"><span>Extra-long button to let you appreciate the effect.</span></button>
```

This is the CSS file:

```
.btn {
  position: relative;

  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;

  overflow: hidden;

  border-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);

  background-color: #2ecc71;
  color: #ecf0f1;

  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}

.btn > * {
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  display: block;
  width: 0;
  padding-top: 0;

  border-radius: 100%;

  background-color: rgba(236, 240, 241, .3);

  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btn:active:before {
  width: 120%;
  padding-top: 120%;

  transition: width .2s ease-out, padding-top .2s ease-out;
}

/* Styles, not important */
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: #34495e;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.btn.orange {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.btn.orange:hover, .btn.orange:focus {
  background-color: #d35400;
}

.btn.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.btn.red:hover, .btn.red:focus {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
```

You can also try the snippet out on the codepen I linked.

How should I proceed? Is there a way to preserve the effect while putting the buttons on a line?

Comment: What do you mean by inline buttons, the buttons have display set to inline OR, you want to display all buttons inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a container with display: flex.

```
<div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn" type="button"><span>Button</span></button>

    <button class="btn orange" type="button"><span>Medium-length button</span></button>

    <button class="btn red" type="button"><span>Extra-long button to let you appreciate the effect.</span></button>
</div>
```

And then

```
.btn-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: This one works, but the buttons end up being very close together. How do I space them a little?

Comment: .btn class has margin: 30px auto; where "auto" is the horizontal margin, just change it to 50px or whatever you want to space up the buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block;` to do this. When using `inline-block` you will keep the spacing properties you need, whilst allowing the element to display inline.

You can read more about inline block on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp).

> Compared to display: inline, the major difference is that display: inline-block allows to set a width and height on the element.
>
> Also, with display: inline-block, the top and bottom margins/paddings are respected, but with display: inline they are not.

Another way would be to make a parent wrapper that is `display: flex;` and align the children as you need using [flexbox properties](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) - but in this . case a simple `display: inline-block` should work.

Comment: Yes. But I think there are some parameters in the CSS I posted conflicting with that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.btn {
  position: relative;

  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;

  overflow: hidden;

  border-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);

  background-color: #2ecc71;
  color: #ecf0f1;

  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}

.btn > * {
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  display: block;
  width: 0;
  padding-top: 0;

  border-radius: 100%;

  background-color: rgba(236, 240, 241, .3);

  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btn:active:before {
  width: 120%;
  padding-top: 120%;

  transition: width .2s ease-out, padding-top .2s ease-out;
}

/* Styles, not important */
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: #34495e;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.btn.orange {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.btn.orange:hover, .btn.orange:focus {
  background-color: #d35400;
}

.btn.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.btn.red:hover, .btn.red:focus {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
.all-btn ul li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}




<h1>Material design buttons (CSS-only)</h1>

<h2>Material design buttons with a ripple effect. This is CSS-only so there is no mouse detection, the ripple effect always starts from the same point.</h2>
<div class="all-btn">
  <ul>
    <li><button class="btn" type="button"><span>Button</span></button></li>

    <li><button class="btn orange" type="button"><span>Medium-length button</span></button></li>

<li><button class="btn red" type="button"><span>Extra-long button to let you appreciate the effect.</span></button></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```